When is it appropriate to assign a unique_ptr to a shared_ptr?
This is a follow up to the question that was asked here: Does C++11 unique_ptr and shared_ptr able to convert to each other's type? and more specifically the top voted answer.
The snippet that caught my attention was this:

This is a key part of why std::unique_ptr is so well suited as a factory function return type. Factory functions can’t know whether callers will want to use exclusive ownership semantics for the object they return or whether shared ownership (i.e., std::shared_ptr) would be more appropriate. By returning a std::unique_ptr, factories provide callers with the most efficient smart pointer, but they don’t hinder callers from replacing it with its more flexible sibling.

And then I saw a duplicate question is assigning unique_ptr to shared_ptr allowed? that had a comment:

Why shouldn't be? It's even safer than assigning regular pointer...[more text here].

However the user did not elaborate why it was safer than assigning a regular pointer. I am wondering in what cases would it be best to assign a unique_ptr to a shared_ptr? If I understood correctly, the first quoted section, cases like this are the best: (Let's assume that we have a working base class Car and all of the CarTypes inherit from Car.)
enum class CarType
{
    Sedan,
    SUV,
    Crossover,
    Truck,
    Bus
};

class MyRental
{
  public:
    MyRental();

    void assignRentalCar(CarType type);
    void doDriveAction();
    void doTurnAction();
    void doParkAction();

  private:
    std::shared_ptr<Car> currentCar;
    std::shared_ptr<Bus> bus; // a Oversized Vehicle Bus : (public OversizedCar : public Car)

};

From above in our private members lets say we have a special case where the member variable, bus, inherits from an OversizeCar class which inherits from a Car class.
MyRental::MyRental() : currentCar(std::make_unique<Sedan>()),
                       bus(std::make_unique<Bus>())
{}
                         

void MyRental::assignRentalCar(CarType type)
{
  switch(type)
  {
    case CarType::SUV: currentCar = std::make_unique<SUV>(); break;
    case CarType::Crossover: currentCar = std::make_unique<Crossover>(); break;
    case CarType::Truck: currentCar = std::make_unique<Truck>(); break;
    case CarType::Bus: currentCar = bus; break; // allowed because currentCar is a shared_ptr
    case CarType::Sedan:
    case default: currentCar = std::make_unique<Sedan>(); break;
  }
}

void MyRental::doDriveAction()
{
  currentCar->handleDrive();
}

void MyRental::doTurnAction()
{
  currentCar->handleTurn();
}

void MyRental::doParkAction()
{
  currentCar->handlePark();
}

Is this an appropriate case to assign a unique_ptr to a shared_ptr? And if so why is it appropriate? If it is not appropriate and better to assign shared_ptrs instead, when is it best to assign a unique_ptr to a shared_ptr?

TLDR : Never.  A shared pointer models shared ownership and a unique pointer unique ownership. These are two different concepts (the conversion should not even have been supported by C++)

It's "safer" because the ownership policy is very clear.  Whereas, Foo* p = q; does p own — and responsible for destruction of — the Foo now?  Or does q still own the Foo?  Foo* p = std::exchange(q, nullptr); would be clearer on the intent, but most code that uses raw pointers just does the Foo* p = q; way, and leaves figuring out the ownership as an exercise for the reader.

I have two different answers here haha.

My answer was the general case. I can see the case where a factory returns a unique_pointer to you (never a raw pointer). And then you decide to share that ownership with other parts of the code but I still would model that differently (e.g. move the unique pointer to another class which you then can share)

So like always you have to design these things up front, not just change one into the other becuase it seems convenient at the time

"By returning a std::unique_ptr, factories provide callers with the most efficient smart pointer, but they don’t hinder callers from replacing it with its more flexible sibling." - If the caller wants shared ownership, creating a std::shared_ptr via std::make_shared() is more efficient than creating a std::shared_ptr from a std::unique_ptr. Using std::make_shared() involves just 1 memory allocation, whereas transferring a std::unique_ptr to a std::shared_ptr involves 2 memory allocations.

Suppose I own something, and then say "I will give up my ownership of this thing as long as it is shared by all those who so desire". I am aware that there are those who would rather die than submit to such communism, but would you really consider it unsafe? Indeed, it is "safer" than giving away ownership of something that I can't be absolutely sure is mine.

"However the user did not elaborate why it was safer than assigning a regular pointer" -- Probably because (it was just a comment and) the reasons correspond to the reasons why std::unique_ptr is safer than an owning raw pointer. That is, the reasons have little (if anything) to do with std::shared_ptr.

Your code's not very good (or a good illustration for exploring your own questions about unique vs shared ptrs) because the factory function isn't factored to be usable independently of the MyRental class.  Generally, you want the factory to be usable by anyone interested in Car objects, even if they're not using MyRental objects.  The textbook approach is for a standalone or static member factory function to return a std::unique_ptr<Car>, so those who want unique ownership already have it, and those that want shared can do the conversion with no more overhead than from a raw pointer

As Remy points out though, shared pointers are famously more efficiently created by make_shared<T>(...) - as it can do one memory allocation for the control block and the first shared pointer.  For that reason, if you really care about supporting optimal performance you could have distinct factory functions - ideally sharing implementation and using a template argument to determine the return type and make_X function used.


I am wondering in what cases would it be best to assign a unique_ptr to a shared_ptr?

You're overthinking this, but I suppose it is a valid question. The scenarios where an assignment is reasonable are when the following hold.

You have a value, u, of type U to assign from.
You have an object, s, of type S to assign to.
The assignment s = u is syntactically valid and useful for your code.
The construction S s(u) is not a reasonable option. If you can reasonably use construction instead of assignment, do that.

These criteria are good for many types, including when U is std::unique_ptr&& and S is std::shared_ptr. One caveat for the smart pointer case is that the assignment must be from an rvalue. That is, if the unique_ptr is not being returned by a function, you probably have to move it, as in s = std::move(u). Note that this move assignment will result in u being null; you will not have s and u point to the same object at the same time.
Basically, use assignment when it is natural, and avoid it when it is not.

You did ask about "best" rather than "good", though. That brings in another consideration, also not particular to smart pointers: avoid unnecessary conversions. Assigning a unique_ptr<Truck> to a shared_ptr<Car> involves a more complex conversion than converting a shared_ptr<Truck> to a shared_ptr<Car>. In your example, you could readily simplify by replacing std::make_unique with std::make_shared. Keep it simple, and don't push others to ask "does a unique_ptr convert to a shared_ptr?"
Basically, stick to shared_ptr when that is an option.
